# mingw get cursor position (console)

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I don't want to use `windows.h` because I will be compiling with mingw `gcc`.
I want to get the cursor position of the console, without using any external libraries. So, how would I get the cursor position of the terminal?

Comment: use library of windows with gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get the cursor position of the console, without using any external libraries.

This isn't possible in standard C, it knows nothing about the mouse, cursor or even the screen. You *must* use platform-specific libraries.

For the record, I believe Mingw supports windows.h just fine.